# affine transformation using nearest neighbor in python

Tags: python, image-processing, nearest-neighbor, image-scaling, affinetransform

I want to make an affine transformation and afterwards use nearest neighbor interpolation while keeping the same dimensions for input and output images. I use for example the scaling transformation T= [[2,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,1]]. Any idea how can I fill the black pixels with nearest neighbor ? I tryied giving them the min value of neighbors' intensities. For ex. if a pixel has neighbors [55,22,44,11,22,55,23,231], I give it the value of min intensity: 11. But the result is not anything clear..

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Importing the original image and init the output image
img = plt.imread('/home/left/Desktop/computerVision/SET1/brain0030slice150_101x101.png',0)
outImg = np.zeros_like(img)

# Dimensions of the input image and output image (the same dimensions)
(width , height) = (img.shape[0], img.shape[1])

# Initialize the transformation matrix
T = np.array([[2,0,0], [0,2,0], [0,0,1]])

# Make an array with input image (x,y) coordinations and add [0 0 ... 1] row
coords = np.indices((width, height), 'uint8').reshape(2, -1)
coords = np.vstack((coords, np.zeros(coords.shape[1], 'uint8')))

output = T @ coords

# Arrays of x and y coordinations of the output image within the image dimensions
x_array, y_array = output[0] ,output[1]
indices = np.where((x_array >= 0) & (x_array < width) & (y_array >= 0) & (y_array < height))

# Final coordinations of the output image
fx, fy = x_array[indices], y_array[indices]

# Final output image after the affine transformation
outImg[fx, fy] = img[fx, fy]
```

The input image is:

[image]

The output image after scaling is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well you could simply use the opencv resize function

```
import cv2 
new_image = cv2.resize(image, new_dim, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
```

it'll do the resize and fill in the empty pixels in one go

[more on cv2.resize](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it manually, then you could simply detect dark pixels in resized image and change their value to mean of 4 neighbour pixels (for example - it depends on your required alghoritm)
See: nereast neighbour, bilinear, bicubic, etc.

Comment: I use the value as the first nearest neighbor and also used to full it with the min value of nearest neighbor and also the mean of the neighbors, but the result is not what I expect...